# Adding corresponding values of Tuple in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a list for example: [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] and the function should return me the sum of the corresponding Tuples. So, this list should return (9,12). I know how to make the tuples add up individually but I have having troubles doing it them together.

```
sumSecondTuple list = foldl (\acc (x,y) -> (+) y acc) 0 list  
    sumFirstTuple list = foldl (\acc (x,y) -> (+) x acc) 0 list
```

I have this much  so far. Is there a way I can incooperate them together?

Comment: `sumTuples list = foldl (\(xAcc, yAcc) (x,y) -> (xAcc + x, yAcc + y)) (0,0) list`

Comment: @Alec This works. Thank you so much.

Comment: alternatively `sumTuples xs = (sumOver fst, sumOver snd)
    where sumOver x = sum $ map x xs
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `foldr1`:

`foldr1 :: Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a`

In this case,

```
sumSecondTuple :: Num a => [(a,a)] -> (a,a)
sumSecondTuple = foldr1 f
    where
        f = (\ (a,b) (c,d) -> (a+c,b+d) )
```

However, `sumSecondTuple []` returns an exception `Prelude.foldr1: empty list`. So, it's better to use `foldr` than use `foldr1` on this occasion.